# selecting a CA cert through KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias

Tags: android, ssl, keychain

I could ask user to install my PKCS12 CA certificate using `createInstallIntent` of Android keychain. Now I am trying to fetch back that installed certificate from keychain through `KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias`. Here when a user selects a cert, I could get a call back to `alias`. With that alias I could get the private key and cert chain programatically. Now I want to know; by user selecting this cert does it means that selected cert will be added (by OS) to all subsequent network calls made by the app? or do I still need to add that cert manually to my network requests?

I use a Volley for network operations and until now I have been adding a PKCS12 cert through the following code:

```
 KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            keyStore.load(
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64Helper.decodeIntoByteArray(PKCS12_CERT_AS_STRING),
                    PKCS12_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, PKCS12_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
            HurlStack hurlStack = new HurlStack(null, sslContext.getSocketFactory());
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MyApplication.getInstance().getAppContext(), hurlStack);
```

So after installing My CA cert to android keychain and making user to choose that cert in the system prompt; do I still need to do the above process to add the cert to my volley request or will this be taken care by Android OS?